# power bi histogram, frequency is distinct dates, values is sum of values for each date

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax

So I have a query that looks like this:

```
datetoapply, origin, type, amount
4/10/2019, A, closed, 125
4/11/2019, A, open, 100
4/11/2019, B, closed, 90
4/12/2019, A, open, 80
4/13/2019, A, open, 125
4/13/2019, B, open, 125
4/13/2019, C, closed, 150
```

In the report, the user can filter by origin, type, and date using slicers.

I need to create a histogram where the values are the sum of the amounts for any given day that meet all the slicer criteria and the frequency is the number of dates that fall within that given range.

For example, if the slicers didn't exclude any data, the histogram might take this form (based on above sample data):

```
range, distinct dates
0-101, 1
101-201, 2
201-301, 1
```

Keep in mind that the ranges should not be constant, this is a very big dataset and depending on the choices made in the slicers the ranges could be small or huge. One possibility would be using the standard deviation to determine the ranges, so there would be a range for everything within -1,1,-2,2, etc. standard deviations from the mean. I'm also open to just setting a desired number of bins.

I have tried everything and can't get the histogram to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your bins dependent on your slicer selection or can you use a standard set of bins for the whole dataset?

Comment: The min and max of each bin is dependent, the number of bins can stay constant.

Comment: It will be quite difficult if you need the axis labeled by the bin ranges since that requires using a measure as a category column. Would it be acceptable to label the axis with quartiles/percentiles instead?

Comment: yes absolutely.